# get result string independently order of given characters

Tags: mysql, regex, search

In my table '*table1*' and column '*code*' I have the varchar "New York", for instance.

Given for example, the characters 'yk' I want to get the "New York".

I can get it using REGEXP in MySql with the query below

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (code) REGEXP '.*y+.*k+.*';
```

The problem is that I want get the same result if the search characters are 'ky'

Anyone can help me?

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

how 'bout two separate regexes:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (code) REGEXP '.*y.*' and (code) REGEXP '.*k.*';
```

Also, I'm not familar with mysql regexes, but should this work:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (code) REGEXP 'y' and (code) REGEXP 'k';
```

or this

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (code) like '%y%' and (code) like '%k%';
```

Comment: I think the third solution is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

How about just searching twice:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (code) REGEXP '.*y+.*k+.*' OR (code) REGEXP '.*k+.*y+.*';
```

Comment: The example I gave was just 2 characters, but I can have 3, 4, or more, so will be impossible make all combinations.